# How to subtract two columns from each other when using case expression

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-query-builder

I want to export some results in Excel from the Model method, so I added this,

```
public static function getAllData()
    {
    $records = DB::table('orders as t1')
        ->leftjoin('payments as t2', 't1.ord_id', '=', 't2.pay_ord_id')
        ->select(DB::raw("case when pay_type_id=190 then t1.ord_total - t2.pay_amount as Paid_Amount_Online"),
        ...
        ->get();
    
    return $records;
    }
```

So as you can see I want to check if the payment type id is equals to **190** that means user has paid it with wallet and the remaining balance is paid online.

So in order to get the **Paid_Amount_Online** value, I need to subtract the whole order total amount from the payment amount:

```
case when pay_type_id=190 then t1.ord_total - t2.pay_amount as Paid_Amount_Online
```

But this obviously wrong and returns syntax error.

So I wonder how can I subtract the amount values from eachother when using sql case expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
case when pay_type_id=190 then t1.ord_total - t2.pay_amount as Paid_Amount_Online
```

is raw SQL injected into the query. The syntax is like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END
```

That is:

- you start the expression with `case`
- there can be one or more conditions

  - a condition starts with a `when`, followed by an expression, continuing with a `then` and ending with the actual value
  - you may have an `else` that stands for a fallback logic when all conditions are false
- you end the expression with `end`

In your code you have a `case`, a condition with a `when` and a `then`, but you are missing its `end`.

Answer (score 0):

check :

```
public static function getAllData()
{
$records = DB::table('orders as t1')
    ->leftjoin('payments as t2', 't1.ord_id', '=', 't2.pay_ord_id')
    ->select(DB::raw("case when pay_type_id=190 then t1.ord_total - t2.pay_amount end as Paid_Amount_Online"),
    ...
    ->get();

return $records;
}
```

before as use `end`

Answer (score 0):

> here is your solution, if you got any error after this, please post error also, in my answer you can remove else or you can give your comment -

```
 public static function getAllData()
    {
    $records = DB::table('orders as t1')
        ->leftjoin('payments as t2', 't1.ord_id', '=', 't2.pay_ord_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('(CASE WHEN t1.pay_type_id=190 Then t1.ord_total - t2.pay_amount ELSE "No Action Found" End) AS Paid_Amount_Online'),
        ...
        ->get();
    
    return $records;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot END at the end of your case expression:

```
public static function getAllData()
        {
        $records = DB::table('orders as t1')
            ->leftjoin('payments as t2', 't1.ord_id', '=', 't2.pay_ord_id')
            ->select(DB::raw("case when pay_type_id=190 then t1.ord_total-t2.pay_amount as Paid_Amount_Online END as something"),
            ...
            ->get();
        
        return $records;
        }
```